# UITextView and NSMutableAttributedText

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

`UITextView` shows formatted text when I use `NSAttributedString`:

```
NSAttributedString* s1 =
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello there!"
                                attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor], NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]}];
_textView.attributedText = s1;
```

However, when I use `NSMutableAttributedString` I see appended attributed strings without formatting. Formatting will be shown for the string it was initialized only.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]
    NSMutableAttributedString *emailBody = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor], NSFontAttributeName: font}];
if (_person.firstName.length > 0) {
    [emailBody appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:_person.firstName attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption1]}]];
    [emailBody appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:nil]];
}
if (_person.lastName.length > 0) {
    [emailBody appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:_person.lastName attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption2]}]];
    [emailBody appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"\n" attributes:nil]];
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `NSAttributedString` appended to `NSMutableAttributedString`, it has its own attributes.